# Swift TimeInterval to Date

Tags: swift, xcode

I've extended Date to return a string like so:

```
extension Date {
    func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {
        print("Date RIGHT NOW: \(self)")
        let secondsAgo = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(self))

        if secondsAgo >= 86400 * 2 {
            return "\(((secondsAgo / 60) / 60) / 24) days ago"
        } else if secondsAgo >= 86400 {
            return "\(((secondsAgo / 60) / 60) / 24) day ago"
        } else if secondsAgo > 7200 {
            return "\((secondsAgo / 60) / 60) hours ago"
        } else if secondsAgo >= 3600 {
            return "\((secondsAgo / 60) / 60) Hour ago"
        } else if secondsAgo < 60 {
            return "\(secondsAgo) seconds ago"
        } else if secondsAgo > 119 {
            return "\(secondsAgo / 60) minutes ago"
        }

        return "\(secondsAgo / 60) minute ago"
    }
}
```

I have a timeInterval in a database for every post a user makes but I want to know how to make this extension work to the TimeInterval of the post.

Comment: Is you simply want to convert a `TimeInterval` to a `Date` and then to a `String`, there's a few `Date` initialisers that can take a `TimeInterval`. If it's something else that you are after, you'll need to provide more details as your question is rather vague.

Comment: Oops, make that “*If* you simply want to…”

Comment: Try looking at `DateComponentsFormatter`, which does more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're almost there! You're already calculating a `TimeInterval` and simply need to make that the type extended instead:

```
extension TimeInterval {
    func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {
        let secondsAgo = Int(self)

        if secondsAgo >= 86400 * 2 {
            return "\(((secondsAgo / 60) / 60) / 24) days ago"
        } else if secondsAgo >= 86400 {
            return "\(((secondsAgo / 60) / 60) / 24) day ago"
        } else if secondsAgo > 7200 {
            return "\((secondsAgo / 60) / 60) hours ago"
        } else if secondsAgo >= 3600 {
            return "\((secondsAgo / 60) / 60) Hour ago"
        } else if secondsAgo < 60 {
            return "\(secondsAgo) seconds ago"
        } else if secondsAgo > 119 {
            return "\(secondsAgo / 60) minutes ago"
        }

        return "\(secondsAgo / 60) minute ago"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use Calendar methods for calendrical calculations. Not everyday has 24 hours

Comment: That's close to what I want thanks! But I'd like to know how to calculate the time of the post compared to the current time.